# Proof of König's theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, network-flow, network

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. $H\subseteq V$ is called a vertex cover of $G$ iff $(u,v)\in E\Rightarrow u\in H\vee v\in H$. Now let's assume $G$ is bipartite, i.e. $V=V_1 \cup V_2$ and $E\subseteq V_1\times V_2$. Then [König's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_%28graph_theory%29) states, that the cardinality of a maximum matching in $G$ equals the minimum size of any vertex cover of $G$.

I'm asked to proof the theorem in the following steps:

1. Transform the given graph into a flow network $N:=(V',E',s,t,c)$ such that any flow of value $x$ in $N$ corresponds to a matching of cardinality $x$ in $G$ and any matching of cardinality $x$ in $G$ defines a flow of value $x$ in $N$.
2. Show that any vertex cover $H$ of $G$ defines a cut of capacity $H$ in $N$
3. Show that any cut of capacity $k$ in $N$ defines a vertex cover of size $k$ in $G$

(1) I've set $V'=V\cup\left\{s,t\right\}$, $E'=E\cup \left\{(s,u):u\in V_1\right\}\cup\left\{(v,t):v\in V_2\right\}$ and $c(u,v)\equiv 1$ for all $(u,v)\in E'$. Then I've proved the statement.

(2) Now I would like to proof (2) as well, but I don't think it's a correct statement. Please consider $V_1=\left\{u\right\}$ and $V_2=\left\{v\right\}$. Then $G$ is a valid bipartite graph and $H=\left\{u,v\right\}$ is a vertex cover in $G$. But, any cut of $N$ has a capacity of $1\ne 2=|H|$.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Please consider the following example
[image]

Let $V_1=\left\{A,B,C,D\right\}$ and $V_2=\left\{E,F,G,H\right\}$. The red line illustrates a cut with capacity $4$ (visualized by the orange edges each of capacity $1$). If the bold black edge from $G$ to $B$ is not present, the green nodes are a vertex cover set with cardinality $4$. The edge $(G,B)$ doesn't contribute to the capacity  of any cut, because its capacity is $0$. So, how do you build a vertex cover set formally if (G,B) is present?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of constructing $V^\prime$ so that the edges $(u, v) \in E$ have capacity $1$, let such $(u,v)$ have *infinite* capacity and the edges $(s,u)$ and $(v,t)$ have capacity $1$.

Then an integral flow (and there must be a maximum flow which is integral) can send at most one unit of flow through each $u\in V_1$ and $v \in V_2$, and one can tell which pairs it matches by whether there is flow going through the edge $(u,v)$ (if there is, this forces the flow through $(s,u)$ and $(v,t)$ as well as the flow through $(u,v)$ to be 1).  The total flow $x$ is the number of such matched pairs.  This is slightly less obvious than in your original construction, but still true.  This gives you (1).

On the other hand, any *finite* weight cut will contain only edges of the form $(s,u)$ and $(v,t)$ (which each have weight $1$).  Check (for (2) and (3)) that a vertex cover corresponds a cut which contains $(s,u)$ for every $u \in V_1$ in the vertex cover, and $(v,t)$ for every $v \in V_2$ in the vertex cover.

After this you are done by the min-cut max-flow theorem.

Comment: I've edited my question and provided an example which illustrates my problem.